# How can I pass global variables into a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `tabletop.js` to cycle through spreadsheet data hosted on google sheets and having trouble understanding how to pass a value into a `showinfo` function so that it can be used to cycle through the spreadsheet.

The data is initialized with:

```
function init() {
  Tabletop.init({
    key: public_spreadsheet_url,
    callback: showInfo,
    simpleSheet: true,
    parseNumbers: true
  })
}
```

and then a loop cycles through by:

```
function showInfo(data) {
  var changingvalue = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].mainvalue == changingvalue) {
      //execute code
    }
```

My question is, how can I define var changingvalue outside of the function showInfo so that I can run the showInfo function again with a different changing value?

I want to eventually execute this function each time a button on the site with the values 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. associated is clicked.   Currently, the function is only activated once when the website is loaded and the `init()` is called.

Comment: Just define the variable at a higher scope than `showInfo` and it'll be accessible.

Comment: You could pass in `changingvalue` as a parameter.